# How to convert numeric values to percentage

Tags: python

```
 A = 860
 B = 123
 C = (B/A) * 100
 Print("the proportion of C", round(C, 2), "%")
```

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column

Output
The proportion of C is 14.3%

Comment: I have updated that. I already multiply by 100.

Comment: The problem seems to the inside the "print" statement. Are you sure you pasted the code correctly? Also, try ´´´print(f"the proportion of C {round(C, 2)} %")´´´.

Comment: If that is your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it but same error

Comment: Why is this a pyspark question and not a python question?

Comment: Print (capital P) is not a recognized function. Are you using your own definition?

Comment: The p is lower case. That was typo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have a problem with print function just take a look this works for me

```
A = 860
B = 123
C = (B/A) * 100
print("the proportion of C", round(C, 2), "%")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the general formula for getting a percentage.

```
((final value - start value)/(final value))*100
```

and for print it, you must change it to string

```
print(str(round(C, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems correct except for a syntax error `Print` instead of `print`. You should either use `print` or fix your own `Print` function.

Comment: The p is lower case, sorry for the typo error

Comment: Then your syntax is correct - make sure you don't override the `print` function anywhere